# Altering input files in a Python toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters, error-000732

I'm trying to add a temporary field to one of the input feature classes in my Python toolbox.

```
arcpy.AddWarning("Adding field of type " + fieldType.upper() + " to FC " + varFC + " called " + tempField)
arcpy.AddField(varFC, tempField, fieldType.upper())
```

The first line outputs as I'd expect

> ("Adding field of type DOUBLE to FC C:\foobar\Test.gdb\inputFC called Population_temp"), but the second line raises an error:
>
> Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset C:\foobar\TEST.gdb\outputFC does not exist or is not supported
>   Failed to execute (AddField).

`outputFC` is the output parameter in the Python toolbox, and NOT what's stored in `varFC` (which is an input parameter). I can't figure out why Arc is referencing `outputFC` at all, unless Python toolboxes will only allow alteration of parameters designated as output?

---

If anyone is wondering the specific answer to my question, you can alter input parameters. You just have to use valid arcpy commands.

Comment: It's been a while since I used ArcGIS/Python scripting but I would suggest trying a shorter simpler variable name like `poptemp` just to see if that makes any difference. Also check if it should be `DOUBLE` or `double` (you are passing in `double` on creation. Should it be `AddField_management ` http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000 ? I couldn't find `AddField` in the docs....

Comment: I have read your question 3 times and still can't figure out what's the problem is :) can you provide more clear info on the input and output params and the script configuration? Having the full code of the script would be helpful to get the context.

Comment: Ahh, man. I totally forgot the `_management` part of `AddField_management()`. Not the first time I've done that, and probably won't be the last! Thank you @djq !! Also thanks for trying to decipher my incomprehensible nonsense, @Alex Tereshenkov

Comment: You're welcome! I recommend using the debugger `ipdb` instead of `print`. Install `ipdb` and then add `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` where the problem occurs. This way you can jump into the terminal and interact with code at this breakpoint.

Comment: You can also use the module form, if it helps you remember (ie. `arcpy.management.AddField`).